# Azure Notification Hubs Register Device Error 404

Tags: c#, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

This is the first time I'm using Azure Notification Hubs and I'm having some trouble getting it working properly with my application.

The part I'm stuck on (at the moment) is registering my device with the notification hub.  I'm using the backend method to do the registration ... that is, I'm creating an Installation object and using the CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync method to register the device via my Web API.  I'm only testing it at this stage so I'm hitting my API endpoint with dummy data via Postman.

When I step through my code, I'm getting the following error when I execute CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync ...

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. Entity does not
>   exist.TrackingId:203cba37-007d-4dcb-ae25-ced33fa012aa_G1,TimeStamp:2/4/2018
>   10:24:02 PM

I've tested that I am connecting to the Notification Hub correctly by calling GetAllRegistrationsAsync.  This returns an empty list (expected) and no error ... so I have my endpoints set up correctly.  I'm wondering if there is a problem with my dummy data?  For the installation Id, I've just created a random GUID (Guid.NewGuid).  The Device ID and Push Notification Handle are random numbers and letters.  And I'm testing this for the Android platform (NotificationPlatform.Gcm).

Has anyone seen this error before and know what it means?  Am I able to just use random data for testing purposes (I'm only interested in registering devices at this stage) or do I need legitimate data (real device id's, etc)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that I had the wrong value for Hub Name when instantiating the NotificationHub object using `NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString`.  I was using the namespace, instead of the hub name (visible on the Overview tab in the Azure Portal).

Answer (score 1):

The `CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync` method would essentially invoke the REST API [Create or Overwrite an Installation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/mt621153.aspx). When you register with a notification hub from your custom backend using the Installation, the core code would look like as follows:

```
NotificationHubClient hubclient = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(listenConnString, hubName);
await hubclient.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(installation);
```

**Note:** You could install the [Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs/) package for back end operations.

For a simpler way, I just created a console application and test this operation as follows:

[image]

**Note:** I just created a new Azure Notification Hub and did not set any notification settings. And I set a GUID as the `InstallationId` and a random string as the `PushChannel`, the rest operation could work as expected.

And I could retrieve the previous added registration as follows:

[image]

> Has anyone seen this error before and know what it means? Am I able to just use random data for testing purposes (I'm only interested in registering devices at this stage) or do I need legitimate data (real device id's, etc)?

The operation could work on my side, I would recommend you debug your application and leverage [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the network traces to narrow this issue. Moreover, you could follow [Registration management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management) for more details about registering devices with azure notification hubs.